# Java While Loops

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working on a while loop that I would like to stop while the variable is less than 100. With what I have currently, my output stops at 128 - not sure why it prints 128 when the last output should be 64.  Any pointers?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsectGrowth {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  int numInsects = 0;

  numInsects = 8; 

  System.out.print(numInsects + " ");

  while (numInsects < 100) {
     numInsects = numInsects * 2;
     System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
  }

  System.out.println();

  return;
  }
}
```

Comment: "**stop** while the variable is less than 100"? Then `while (numInsects >= 100)`.

Comment: Dont you mean "I would like to *run* while the variable is less than 100."

Comment: When `numInsects` is `64` is it less than `100`?  What will happen in the loop when this is true?

Comment: `while (2 * numInsects < 100) {`.

Comment: because while is a top tested loop, and before 128 the value of numInsects is 64, so it enters the loop, multiplies 64 * 2 = 128 and prints it. After printing 128, it testes the value of numInsects , which is 128 , so exits.

Comment: Why people down vote this question? whats wrong? Do you want to discourage new member. She asks a question just answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last value printed is 128 because you execute

```
numInsects = numInsects * 2;
```

before

```
System.out.print(numInsects + " ");
```

Therefore the loop stops when `numInsects` is 64, but multiplies it by 2 before printing, hence why you see 128.

Comment: Glad it helped :) If you accept my answer, this question can close.